# JAVA REGEX: Match until the specific character

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this Java code

```
String cookies = TextUtils.join(";",  LoginActivity.msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies());
Log.d("TheCookies", cookies);
Pattern csrf_pattern = Pattern.compile("csrf_cookie=(.+)(?=;)");
Matcher csrf_matcher = csrf_pattern.matcher(cookies);
while (csrf_matcher.find()) {
    json.put("csrf_key", csrf_matcher.group(1));
    Log.d("CSRF KEY", csrf_matcher.group(1));
}
```

The String contains something like this:

```
SessionID=sessiontest;csrf_cookie=e18d027da2fb95e888ebede711f1bc39;ci_session=3f4675b5b56bfd0ba4dae46249de0df7994ee21e
```

Im trying to get the `csrf_cookie` data by using this Regular Expression:

```
csrf_cookie=(.+)(?=;)
```

I expect a result like this in the code:

```
csrf_matcher.group(1);

e18d027da2fb95e888ebede711f1bc39
```

instead I get a:

```
3492f8670f4b09a6b3c3cbdfcc59e512;ci_session=8d823b309a361587fac5d67ad4706359b40d7bd0
```

What is the possible work around for this problem?

Comment: why not match everything but the semicolon? `csrf_cookie=([^;]*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one-liner using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "SessionID=sessiontest;csrf_cookie=e18d027da2fb95e888ebede711f1bc39;ci_session=3f4675b5b56bfd0ba4dae46249de0df7994ee21e";
String cookie = input.replaceAll(".*csrf_cookie=([^;]*).*", "$1");
System.out.println(cookie);

e18d027da2fb95e888ebede711f1bc39
```

### Demo

Note: We could have used a formal regex pattern matcher, and in face you may want to do this if you need to do this search/replacement often in your code.

Comment: That does the job. Thanks! but I'm still curious why does the formal regex pattern matcher don't work?

Comment: @GianLorenzoAbaño It most certainly _would_ work, but it's a bigger effort, and if you just have a quick one time need, sometimes a one-liner like this is preferable, from a convenience and code readability point of view.

Comment: I just realized that you're already using a matcher.  You want to use this pattern: `Pattern.compile("csrf_cookie=([^;]+)");`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting more data than expected because you are using an greedy '+' (It will match as long as it can)

For example the pattern `a+` could match on `aaa` the following: `a`, `aa`, and `aaa`. Where the later is 'preferred' if the pattern is greedy.

So you are matching

`csrf_cookie=e18d027da2fb95e888ebede711f1bc39;ci_session=3f4675b5b56bfd0ba4dae46249de0df7994ee21e;`

as long as it ends with a ';'. The first ';' is skipped with `.+` and the last ';' is found with the possitive lookahead

To make a patter ungreedy/lazy use `+?` instead of `+` (so `a+?` would match `a` (three times) on `aaa` string)

So try with:

`csrf_cookie=(.+?);`

or just match anything that is not a ';'

`csrf_cookie=([^;]*);`

that way you don't need to make it lazy.

Comment: added to the answer

Comment: but in the original question there is no semi-colon at the very end of the string (lazy OP??!!)

Comment: Well, he said `The String contains something like this:` that `something like` could perfectly have another `;`. Else I don't see a way for failing.

Comment: agreed - incomplete question